# Analogy Question

Tags: analogy

I need help completing the following analogy:
I've only tried Treasure and Jewelry for the blanks but it doesn't seem to make sense.

Pirates:Earrings:____

Pimps:____:Bail
???

Comment: Pirates wear Earrings; Pimps wear Jewelry .... ok, makes sense I guess. I don't know what the relationship between Pimps and Bail is though, so I couldn't guess what the "equivalent" for Pirates would be.

Comment: And what's the purpose of such a question? What's the real question?

Answer (score 1):

Pirates to earrings: the successful criminal action resulting in booty. 
The next step would be relative to getting caught (the comparative analogy being bail). Now when a pirate catches you, he might make you walk the plank, but what did the Royal Navy do to pirates when caught? If it had to be one word, I would say "shipwreck," but that doesn't seem quite right. "Cannonball" is too much about the action rather than the result.

Looking at the bottom example, we are needing to look at the proceeds from the crime analogous to earrings. I would say "cash" works better than "money." Who knows? Maybe pimps these days have a PayPal account ...